# In GatsbyJs, How to change the S3 path

Tags: amazon-s3, gatsby, strapi

I have the image stored on AWS S3 and when each image is fetched to the front-end; the img source have https://bucketname-temp.s3.amazonaws.com/file-name.jpg

I don't want to show this path to users; there's some plugin or something I can do to change this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you upload your images to another bucket/site, no. The `src` is a reference where the image asset is located so you source will always need to point there, otherwise, the image will be never loaded or it will be unreachable.

The only configuration possible comes to my mind would be using a [Reverse Proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy) but this configuration belongs to your server, not to Gatsby nor the front-end side. If you do so, you'll need to add the `protocol` attribute to your [`gatsby-plugin-s3` configuration](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-s3/#configuration) (which by default it's `undefined`):

> The protocol of your site. If you are using a CDN or reverse-proxy
> (such as CloudFront) in front of S3. then you must fill out this and
> the `hostname` field to ensure redirects work correctly. If you are just
> using your S3 website directly, this is unnecessary.